# Detect phone call termination

Tags: filter, opto-isolator, telephone

I am designing an automated telephone circuit that will work with the PSTN line. I already had a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400128/detect-ring-signal-using-a-low-pass-filter) to detect the incoming ring signal. Now I want to detect whether the opponent person in the line terminated the call. Because I need to cut off the line connection automatically since there will be no one to hang the handset on my telephone side.

So far, I learned that there is a constant beep sound which is generated by the telecom company when the opponent hangs his/her phone and terminates the call. The beep sound has ~2V peak-to-peak and a 5V offset, you can see the DC measurement and AC measurement below:

**DC Measurement:**

[image]

**AC Measurement:**

[image]

I am trying to detect the existence of this signal by an MCU. So far, I tried using an optocoupler but the voltage is not enough for driving an optocoupler. I tried the optocoupler circuit because the input (LINE- and LINE+) must be isolated from the output (GPIO of the MCU).

Are there any already-tested solutions for this kind of applications? Do they just use circuits for amplifying or filtering this signal to detect its existence? I wanted to use a comparator by using the Line for both supply and input but I couldn't get it work.

Comment: Have you tried just a straight OP-amp, band pass filter and a comparator?

Comment: I'm not really experienced with circuit designs, so I'm using the classic methods and try to understand the basics. How should I supply the op-amp? If I supply it with another isolated source, how can I give the input line signal to the op-amp with a reference to this source?

Comment: Classic method would not involve an optocopler. How are you powering everything today? Do you need isolation from the PSTN?

Comment: I have multiple power sources in this board by I don't know how to connect the line to an op-amp in this example. Because I can not combine the **line-** with the ground layer of the power source of the op-amp because there is a potential difference between them. Do you have any reference circuits? Even a block scheme is enough for me to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. You will need to iron out several details. I would suggest installing LTspice if you haven't already and simulate it to get the details.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAvqkP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Better check it for 100 V AC bell ring voltage too.

Comment: @Transistor Ah, yes! Several things to iron out here. Probably cheat and increase R1 value and have something to clamp before the op-amp.

Comment: I'm still working on this schematic, thank you for your answer. I will click accept as soon as I finish!

Comment: @abdullahcinar You're welcome, but wait until you have got it to work. As Transistor said, you probably need to recomputethe filter constants for higher R1 value and add a zener or similar to clamp the 100 VAC ringing. R3 and R4 will need tuning too to give reasonable detection threshold.

Comment: You're right. 100 VAC will be a problem if I don't add a protection for it, thanks for clarifying that. But I will probably have a relay to control the line inputs before directing it to this circuit. So I think I won't need that kind of protection if I use this kind of relay.

Comment: @abdullahcinar Any success?

Comment: I needed to use an external power supply for the opamp and comparator because the phone line was very sensitive to the current draw. The input voltage was decreasing more than my comparison tolerance. Additionally, I used an opamp as a comparator and make this circuit run in a single package IC. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @abdullahcinar Good to hear and glad to be of help!